# How to refer to hardcoded values in code from the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oop

In the (MySQL) database, I'm storing a view hierarchy, with each row in a table referring to a single view. There are several types of views, but they're stored in the same table.

In the application code, each type of view has its own class. Each row in the database instantiates one of these classes.

**How should I refer to these classes from the database, so the application knows which class to use?**

I can think of several possibilities:

- Just specify the class name directly in the table, but this has the disadvantage of having to change lots of rows if the class name changes (which can be done in a single query if required).
- Have a separate table storing class names, and use foreign keys to point to the row storing the correct class name. In this case, I could forgo having an ID field in this lookup table and instead have the class name as the primary key and target foreign key, and rely on a cascading `UPDATE` if the class name changes?

Are there better options available?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to maintain an association between view-names and class-names.

Your bullets suggests, that there can be more than one view for the same class and both of your suggestions would work. The second bullet has the advantage that you can change the class name with a single update. But that doesn't buy you much, because as soon as more than just a single class-name changes, i.e. when the association itself changes, you need to update more than one row.

You might even create a separate table, holding this association. This would be the model for an n:m relationship, which is too general, so you'd have to place a unique constraint on the view-name. Essentially this will just factor out the concern of associating view-names with class-names and allow you to change this mechanism entirely without having to mess with your tables (except the one holding this association).

But actually I would not store any of this stuff in the database 
(I also find it irritating that view-names are stored in the database and not in the application logic). The fact that there are class-names, should be of no concern to your database. This is application logic and it should be handled there. So what you need is a way to instantiate an object when the view-name is known. This looks like a classic *factory* to me. After all, if a class name changes, it is a change in the application code and life is easier, when all resulting changes lie in the application code as well.

Comment: If I don't store the class name anywhere in the database, then how do I know which class to instantiate in the application logic? Or should I use some separate identifier, which would still have to be hardcoded into the class somewhere?